# Dojox charting stacked bars from memory store

Tags: json, charts, dojo

I have a json like:

```
[
{
    "User": "Bob",
    "Forums": [
        {
            "Name": "General",
            "Count": 5
        },
        {
            "Name": "Help",
            "Count": 10
        }
    ]
},
{
    "User": "Andy",
    "Forums": [
        {
            "Name": "General",
            "Count": 5
        },
        {
            "Name": "Troubles",
            "Count": 1
        },
        {
            "Name": "Advices",
            "Count": 2
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I'd like to build a chart like this with dojox charting:

[image: Example]

So that Y axis has every user in that json and the x axis shows the total count the user has posts on forum. The picture and the json counts don't match but hope you get the idea.

It would also be a must to see the forum name under the count number. I want to sort all the users so that the most post counts is on top and it shows how the user posts are divided across forums.

It seems I fail to understand how do I create a series per user per bar. If I try to create a series like: Bob: [2,4] and Andy: [1,4] Then it will map the first indexes of both on first bar and second indexes on second bar. I'd just like to have that 1 array represent one stacked bar. Is this even possible with stacked bars or what should be the correct approach ?

Comment: Its being difficult to understand what you want to achieve.. it will be more helpful if you can add some sample or similar example... what is the role of two different colors in it?

Comment: @Developerrr Well as I said, "The picture and the json counts don't match but hope you get the idea." I couldn't make a proper example. What I meant was that the total stack would display total post count and different colors would mean different forum count as shown in JSON.